# Can't start react in cmd

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I've been trying to type npm start in the command prompt but it shows missing script: start.. I tried adding start script at package.json file but i get the error failed to parse json.

````
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1"
  }
}

"scripts": {
  "start": "node react-app.js"
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can change start code。

```
 "start": "react-scripts start"
```

your code will start with `react-app.js`。but you dont have a javascript file named `react-app`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command `npm run start`